# History of changes to a particular line of code in Subversion

Tags: svn

Is it possible to see the history of changes to a particular line of code in a Subversion repository?

I'd like, for instance, to be able to see when a particular statement was added or when that statement was changed, even if its line number is not the same any more.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I don't know a method for tracking statements through time in Subversion.

It is simple however to see when any particular line in a file was last changed using `svn blame`. Check the SVNBook: [`svn blame` reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html):

**Synopsis**

```
svn blame TARGET[@REV]...
```

**Description**

Show author and revision information in-line for the specified files or URLs. Each line of text is annotated at the beginning with the author (username) and the revision number for the last change to that line.

Comment: You've solved the OP's problem, but I'm still wondering if there's some way to trace the history for a particular line--when there are too many lines and too many revisions to look through manually.

Comment: Many gui tools e.g. tortoiseSVN (on windows) do a good job of building on this functionality to let you walk the history. Typically highlighting any adjacent lines that changed together and making it easy to step into that diff, then pick up the relevant line number from the earlier revision and repeat. I've happily and quickly traced through large repos(> 10 years of age) which have included migrations from CVS and even cut and paste repository cloning as part of the history. For more automation maybe you could import the repo into git and use its more advanced content based blame capability.

Answer (score 49):

In the [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) client there is a very nice feature that lets you:

- blame a file, displaying the last change for each line (this is standard)
- "blame previous revision", after clicking on a particular line in the above view (this is the good one)

The second feature does what it says - it shows the annotated revision preceding the last modification to the line. By using this feature iteratively, you can trace back through the history of a particular line.

Comment: what if blame does not show the line? I have the case that i search for the change of a particular line. Used tortoise->blame Let revision on lates revision. In the file i can see a particular line, in blame i cannot find it.

Comment: That "blame previous revision" is super helpful, didn't know that existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I'd usually:

1. Run `svn blame FILE` first.
2. Note the last revision of the particular line.
3. Do another query with the `-r` argument:

   ```
   svn blame FILE -r 1:REV
   ```
4. Trace manually from there.

Comment: You can get 1. and 2. combined in ```svn annotate $file_path | head -n$line_no | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in two stages:

1. `svn blame /path/to/your/file > blame.tmp`
2. `grep "your_line_of_text" blame.tmp`

You can delete blame.tmp file afterwards if you don't need it.

In principle, a simple script can be written in any scripting language that does roughly the same.

Comment: You don't need to do this. This can be done from the editor itself, for e.g I use VCSAnnotate from vim. and it splits and shows the blame output without leaving the vim editor. Other editors have similar plugins as well

Answer (score 2):

In [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) you can know when each line of your code has been committed using the SVN annotate view, or right click on the file → *Team* → *Show annotation...*.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is how much history is required. As others have pointed out, the short answer is: `svn blame` (see `svn help blame` for details). If you're reaching far back in history or dealing with significant changes, you will likely need more than just this one command.

I just had to do this myself, and found this (ye ole) thread here on SO. Here's what I did to solve it with just the `CLI`, specifically for my case where an API had changed (e.g. while porting someone's far outdated work (not on a branch, *arrgh!*) back into a feature branch based off of an up-to-date trunk). E.g. function names had changed enough to where it wasn't apparent which function needed to be called.

## Step One

The following command allowed me to page through commits where things had changed in the file "fileName.h" and to see the corresponding revision number (note: you may have to alter the '10' for more or less context per your svn log text).

`svn log | grep -C 10 "fileName.h" | less`

*This results in a list of revisions in which this file was modified.*

## Step Two

Then it was a simple matter of using `blame` (or as others have pointed out, `annotate`) to narrow down to the revisions of interest.

```
cd trunk
svn blame fileName.h@r35948 | less
```

*E.g. found the revision of interest was 35948.*

## Step Three

Having found the revision(s) of interest via blame, a diff can be produced to leverage the SVN tool.

```
svn diff -r35948:PREV fileName.h
```

## Conclusion

Having a visual diff made it much easier to identify the old API names with the newer/updated API names.

Comment: For my specific scenario, if you're lucky and working with code that has good commit messages in the log, you may even be able to `grep` for the old API/function name and find a comment that says something like "*changed func_FindParm to func_GetParm*".

Answer (score 1):

```
svn annotate
```

The AKA *SVN Blame* from [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN).

Answer (score 0):

svn blame shows you which checkin modified any line in a file the last time.

This works on old revisions too.

Answer (score 0):

A start is the command svn blame (or annotate,praise). It will show you when a line of code was last modified and by whom it was modified. e.g.:

```
  4564    wiemann # $Id$
  4564    wiemann # Author: David Goodger <goodger@python.org>
   778    goodger # Copyright: This module has been placed in the public domain.
   217    goodger
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Emacs, the built-in package `vc` can do this.

1. Navigate to the file in question.
2. Run the command `vc-annotate` with either <kbd>M-x</kbd> `vc-annotate` or <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>.
3. Each line will show up with its revision, like a normal `svn blame`.
4. Pressing <kbd>a</kbd> (`vc-annotate-revision-previous-to-line`) will navigate to the revision before the revision at the line you're on.

Answer (score -1):

The command you're looking for is [`svn blame`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html).