# How can I get history of a single line from TortoiseSVN?

Tags: c++, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a line in my code:

```
force=sizeGoalForceKappa*tanh((origRadius-v->radius)/origRadius)*(oldDist+minSpacing-v->radius)/minSpacing;
```

The code is at revision 881. Is there a way to see history of only this line, while ignoring other changes? Showing log for a single file ignores other files. Can I get a log for a single line, or something similar? I would like to see how definition of "force" has evolved over time, and when "force" was introduced. SVN Blame only gives me the revision in which a line was last changed.

Comment: Real answer is in http://stackoverflow.com/a/197895 in linked by @bahrep question - "blame previous revision" blame back in history file, selecting rev-1 for selected string as new base

Comment: @LazyBadger I figured that out by myself, and I up-voted that answer (as well as down-voted the one which claimed it was not possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`svn blame`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html), see [TortoiseSVN manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-blame.html#tsvn-dug-blame-simple). The question can be considered as the duplicate of [History of changes to a particular line of code in Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629/history-of-changes-to-a-particular-line-of-code-in-subversion).

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes for global history of line alternative SCM and it's command may be better: I like Mercurial's grep for it (for SVN repo Mercurial CLI and hgsubversion are required)

`hg grep --all PATTERN FILE` will produce something like this

```
>hg grep --all load_theme_textdomain functions.php
functions.php:2:-:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/translation');
functions.php:2:+:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
functions.php:1:+:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/translation');
```

(explanation: string was added in r1 and edited in r2 - trailing part changed)